# Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Tags: flutter

Why do I get this error. I just want to rename my app from prvi_app to Planets so I followed a tutorial but now I am stuck here and don't know what to do.

[image]

Comment: The reason is exactly written in that log, what are you expecting from us to tell on top of that? The plugins mentioned there are not compatible with each other, remove either one of them or upgrade to compatible versions.

Comment: I just want to change app name...so I can't do that when I have other plugins there?

Comment: Just change the name directly in androidmanifest (For Android) & info.plist (for iOS). Or just change the name first then add the other plugin (remove the previous one which is no longer needed)